# In Javascript/JQuery , how do I read a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a JSON Object that is this:

```
{"success":true, "uploaded_url":uploaded_url}
```

How do I `alert("uploaded_url")`?

Comment: how are you loading the json file?

Comment: http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got a JSON string like this:

```
var myjson = '{"success":true, "uploaded_url":uploaded_url}'
```

you need to parse it into an javascript object first. Most convinient way is to use `JSON.parse()` which pretty much browsers support nowadays (if not, visit http://www.json.org)

```
var myobj = JSON.parse(myjson);
alert(myobj.uploaded_url);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's a JSON file, say `file.json`, it would look like this:

```
$.getJSON("file.json", function(obj) {
  alert(obj.uploaded_url);
});
```

...it really depends how you're loading it, but it's just `object.uploaded_url` or `object["uploaded_url"]` once you have the object.